# How read serial data from USB device in .NET?

Tags: .net, gps, usb, device

I have a Garmin GPS antenna that plugs into my USB port.  I'd like to read the latitude and longitude off of it in my .NET code (i.e. programmatically).  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks very much for any responses.

Answer (score 2):

Going from the bit of information you provided, it might be worth looking at the Garmin SDK available at https://www8.garmin.com/support/commProtocol.html

I'm not sure if your particular device acts like a USB Serial adapter and thus you'd be able to read the NEMA data strings with coordinates that way or if the protocol is more complicated, last time I hooked up a GPS was with raw serial.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to look up in documentation to get informations like in which format your Garmin GPS antenna communicates and what you have to do to that the antenna starts searching for GPS signal for example. 
If there isnt any documentation, its hard to create sth like you want.
If there is one, I would start coding with the [ICSharpCode Usb Library](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpUSBLib/default.aspx) or [LibUsbDotNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/) or [csharp-usb-hid-driver](https://code.google.com/p/csharp-usb-hid-driver/) , which are designed for some low level I/O operations. 
Also, there is a [good tutoria](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Is-that-you-Writing-Better-Software-for-Cool-USB-Hardware)l at channel9 for that, which could be very helpful for your project